# Books about charset and encoding?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, language-agnostic

I want to learn complete and authoritative knowledge about charset and encoding.

That's better that it can provide:

- the orgin,
- the history,
- the standards of charset/encoding,

and also include some specific application/support fields,

such as

1. languages(java, c/c++, javascript, flash..),
2. web(html, http..),
3. database(db encoding, collation, IBM codepage...),
4. mainframe(EBCDIC..)

Who can give a book list about that.

so long to find this book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best one which I found on the subject is- **The Unicode Standard : Worldwide Character Encoding**. By, Unicode foundation itself, currently in its version 5 is an exhaustive research on subject.

**Link:** [http://www.amazon.com/Unicode-Standard-Worldwide-Character-Encoding/dp/0201567881](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201567881)

Though, you may want to check other previous versions as well.

Other books on Unicode:

- Unicode Demystified -by Richard Gillam
- Unicode Explained -by Jukka Korpeta
- Fonts and Encoding
- CJKV Information Processing.

Most of them can be found [HERE](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=unicode).